# Why I don`t have violates foreign key constraints on delete?

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE public.pills (
id serial4 NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(128) NULL,
start_date timestamp NULL,
per_day int4 NULL,
end_date date NULL,
user_id int4 NOT NULL,
schedule_id int4 NULL,
CONSTRAINT pills_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
CONSTRAINT pills_schedule_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (schedule_id) REFERENCES public.schedule(id)
);

CREATE TABLE public.schedule (
    id serial4 NOT NULL,
    "name" varchar(128) NULL,
    description varchar(255) NULL,
    next_run timestamp NULL,
    crontab varchar(50) NULL,
    user_id int4 NULL,
    CONSTRAINT schedule_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

So `pills` depends on `schedule`
For example, I have a schedule with id = 1 and I have some pills with schedule_id = 1. So I expect to get some error when I try to delete the schedule

`delete from schedule where id = 1;`

But I got no error, the schedule is deleted and I still have some pills that link to a non-existing schedule.
Why?

Comment: That's not possible in Postgres. Something must be different from what you show here. See: https://dbfiddle.uk/UwSr4Y5A

Comment: You'll have to tell us how we can reproduce what you see.